# Wordpress image plugin with zoom on image hover

Tags: html, image, wordpress, plugins, gallery

Ive seen some websites where the image zooms in when I hover with the mouse over an image, is there a a plugin for worpress that does that or does it have to be hard coded?

Comment: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/search.php?q=zoom

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you might consider [SwinxyZoom](http://www.swinxyapps.com/pages/apps/swinxy-zoom/index.html) it's like the other image zoom plugins but also integrates with the wordpress editor and plays nicely with touch devices.